# Is it possible to combine a Google Spreadsheets JSON request with a data query?

Tags: json, spreadsheet

I have successfully used the information in the link below to get a JSON output from a Google spreadsheet.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

Is it possible to combine this JSON request with a data query, such as those seen in the link below this?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use the new url for accessing google docs:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%KEY%/gviz/tq?gid=%GID%&tq=%QUERY%
```

%KEY% and %GID% can be found in your spreadsheet's url, and %QUERY% is whatever you are asking the sheet for.  For example, you might ask it to look up a phone number in column B by looking for a name in column A by passing "B where A = 'John Smith'" as the %QUERY%.

Answer (score 0):

seems like it doesn't need the GID parameter :D